# python regex can't match,but matched in javascript with same parttern

Tags: python, regex

code is here:
       import re

```
    res = re.match('bbs1','http://bbs1.people.com.cn/userInfo.do?userNick=%E8%85%BE%E9%A3%9E%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E9%BE%99')
    print(res)
```

It's print None,but when I change parttern to 'http',it matches;
The same parttern in javascript can matched;

```
var url = 'http://bbs1.people.com.cn/userInfo.do?userNick=%E8%85%BE%E9%A3%9E%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E9%BE%99'
url.match(/bbs/)
```

Comment: Use `re.search`.

Comment: You don't need a regex in this case. You can just do `.find` on the string.